# Iphone App release Build Icon crossed

Tags: iphone, sdk, membership, ios-4.2, permission-denied

hi I am having trouble debugging my app on my device and also when I try to build it on release mode, the application file has a some crossed image overlapping on it and the whole icon is lightened in color. however when i install it on my device it works fine. why is this happening?

also when I try to debug my app in the debug mode it troughs a permission denied error.
some message with entitlement data missing ins displayed. what can i do to fix this?

XCODE 3.2.5 and latest 4.2 sdk, I have tried jailbreaking my iphone and did some hacking stuff to get around developer membership before but i have reinstalled the new 3.2.5 with 4.2 recently and have a valid developer membership now.

please help! thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999859/why-is-the-icon-for-my-iphone-app-crossed-out-after-a-build

Answer (score 0):

The "crossed out" icon is normal - it's Mac OS telling you it can't run the file, which is expected since it's made for the phone and not the desktop.