# Why is the icon for my iPhone app crossed-out after a build?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I have just built my first iPhone app, but its icon appears crossed-out. I do have some warnings when I build the code, but why would they cause the app icon to cross? My app has no errors.

Here is what the icon looks like:

[image]

Comment: +1 for asking about it, I don't think other developers would even notice this! (I did, but realized the answer myself.)

Comment: Same thing happens if you build a 64-bit application or a PowerPC application on a computer with which those architectures are incompatible. It's a standard convention in OS X.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I noticed the same. Now here's a question: Did you ever "show package contents" and look at the included images? They're all blank PNGs for me! (I'll start another thread to see if this is expected behaviour.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is completely fine! It just means that your app can't execute on your mac, which is exactly what you want, with an iOS Device build.

(If you ever do a build that doesn't have that cross on it, you've accidentally built your app for the simulator. Good to know, for a subtle future issue that might pop up.)

Comment: Bummer...that makes sense! however some info from Mac OS could have made life easier!.

Comment: Definitely agreed :) if this answers your question, would you mind hitting the checkmark?